# Copula simulation

Tags: probability, statistics, finance, copula

Let $(X_1,X_2)$ be a bivariate random vector where $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $X_2 \sim \mathcal{E}(\lambda)$. We suppose that the dependence function is given by the following copula: 
$$ C(u_1,u_2) = u_1u_2(1 + \theta (1 - u_1)(1 - u_2))$$
where $\theta \in [-1,1]$. I would like to simulate the random vector but i can't achieve to do so.
My idea is to start by simulating $(U_1,U_2)$ (uniforms in $[0,1]$) which have $C$ as cdf : Simulate $U_1$ then simulate $U_2 | U_1$ which has the following cdf :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(U_2 \leq u_2 | U_1 = u_1) & = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{P(U_2 \leq u_2, U_1 \in [u_1, u_1 + \epsilon])}{P(U_1 \in [u_1, u_1 + \epsilon])} \\
& = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{C(u_1+\epsilon,u_2) - C(u_1,u_2)}{\epsilon} \\
& = \partial_{u_1}C(u_1,u_2) \\ 
& = u_2(1+ \theta(1-u_1)(1-u_2)) -\theta u_1u_2(1-u_2) \\ 
& = \theta u_2 ^2(2u_1 - 1) + u_2(1 + \theta - 2\theta u_1)
\end{align*}
My idea is to simulate $U_2 | U_1$ by inverting $\mathbb{P}(U_2 \leq u_2 | U_1 = u_1)$, but it doesn't seem to be invertible.
Any other idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation seems to be correct, and the function you obtained is invertible. You can write it as

$$
\mathbb P(U_2\le u_2\mid U_1=u_1)=\theta(2u_1-1)(u_2^2-u_2)+u_2\;,
$$

and thus

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial u_2}\mathbb P(U_2\le u_2\mid U_1=u_1)=\theta(2u_1-1)(2u_2-1)+1\ge0\;,
$$

since each of the factors in the first term is in $[-1,1]$, with equality obtaining at most at one of the boundary points $u_2=0$ or $u_2=1$. Since the function has positive derivative over $(0,1)$, it is invertible over $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes indeed this works. There is also the following argument: C is a copula so its density $\partial_{u_2}\partial_{u_2} C$ is positive.